# Why table pagination is not working with page search in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the following resource of Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples, namely, make it possible to search in tables with pagination. 
I have tested the code they provide and it works just fine. Now I am trying to unite two codes of them, the table with pages, see the aforementioned link, and the table with search capability, I have a huge table of data, that is why I need to use pagination, otherwise, it does not load; but I want to add as well search.
Here goes a piece of my code, the important part for this question:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.datainputService.loadFASTA().subscribe((data: FASTAElement[]) => {
      this.fastaSample = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<FASTAElement>(this.fastaSample);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

Here goes how I have adapted their code for filtering:

```
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;    
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

An educated guess what may be going wrong? it does work, I have tried several possibilities, but all failed, I know the event is being received, I have tested, I know the is somehow working since I asked to clean the table whenever someone makes a search, and it works; but for updating as it does in the sample case, it does now work alongside pagination.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz instance of your issue ?

Comment: Hey there, I do not know how to do that, but as I as I have time, I will learn how to do it. thanks!

Comment: Just go to stackblitz website https://stackblitz.com/. Start a new angular app, you will find same interface as you get when you create a new angular app. We want you create a minimal code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: thanks, this is not my priority right now, if I have a break, I shall do that! thanks for the attention!